# cast requires that thing is borrowed for `'static`

Tags: rust

Hi so I am playing around with rust. Specifically I am trying to write some code for working with parametric equations. I am maybe going a little crazy with traits and the like...

So I have a trait;

```rust
pub trait ParametricFunction2D {
    fn calculate(&self, t: T) -> (f32, f32);
    fn linspace(&self, n: usize) -> Vec<(f32, f32)> {
        let step_size = 1.0 / n as f32;
        (0..=n)
            .into_iter()
            .map(|i| {
                let t = T::new((i as f32) * step_size);
                self.calculate(t)
            })
            .collect()
    }
    fn start(&self) -> (f32, f32) {
        self.calculate(T::start())
    }
    fn end(&self) -> (f32, f32) {
        self.calculate(T::end())
    }
}
```

I have implemented this trait for `Fn(T) -> (f32, f32)` (where T is just a struct for an f32 that is clamped to [0,1])

```rust
impl<Foo> ParametricFunction2D for Foo
where
    Foo: Fn(T) -> (f32, f32),
{
    fn calculate(&self, t: T) -> (f32, f32) {
        self(t)
    }
}
```

I want to make a concatenation of these `ParametricFunction2D` - that allows for;

1. concat different ones
2. repeat the same one multiple times

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct RcParametricFunction2D {
    func: Rc<dyn ParametricFunction2D>,
}

impl ParametricFunction2D for RcParametricFunction2D {
    fn calculate(&self, t: T) -> (f32, f32) {
        self.func.calculate(t)
    }
}

struct ParametricFunction2DConcat {
    functions: Vec<Box<dyn ParametricFunction2D>>,
}

impl ParametricFunction2DConcat {
    pub fn get_parametric(&self) -> impl Fn(T) -> (f32, f32) + '_ {
        move |t: T| {
            if t == T::start() {
                return self.functions[0].calculate(t);
            }

            if t == T::end() {
                return self.functions[self.functions.len() - 1].calculate(t);
            }

            let gap = 1.0 / self.functions.len() as f32;
            let interp = self.functions.len() as f32 * t.value();
            let index = interp.floor() as usize;

            let diff = t.value() - (index as f32) * gap;

            let interp_t = T::new(diff / gap);

            self.functions[index].calculate(interp_t)
        }
    }

    pub fn repeat(func: Rc<dyn ParametricFunction2D>, n: usize) -> Self {
        let mut functions = Vec::with_capacity(n);
        for _ in 0..n {
            functions.push(RcParametricFunction2D {
                func: Rc::clone(&func),
            });
        }
        Self {
            functions: functions
                .into_iter()
                .map(|f| Box::new(f) as Box<dyn ParametricFunction2D>)
                .collect(),
        }
    }
}
```

use case 1. works fine and use case 2. also (kinda) - if I try to combine the two things I get a problem - see this test;

```
        let eps = f64::EPSILON * 10.0;
        let s1 = Segment {
            start: (0.0, 0.0),
            end: (1.0, 1.0),
        };

        let s1_param = s1.get_parametric();

        let s2 = Segment {
            start: (1.0, 0.0),
            end: (2.0, 1.0),
        };

        let s2_param = s2.get_parametric();

        let concat = ParametricFunction2DConcat {
            functions: vec![Box::new(s1_param), Box::new(s2_param)],
        };
        let concat_param = concat.get_parametric();
        let concat_param = Rc::new(concat_param);
        let rep = ParametricFunction2DConcat::repeat(concat_param, 10);

        let rep = rep.get_parametric();

        rep.calculate(T::start());
        rep.calculate(T::end());
```

N.B The Segment struct is just what you think it would be straight line path from start to end...

I get the following compiler error for line `let concat_param = concat.get_parametric();`

```
error[E0597]: `concat` does not live long enough
   --> src/core.rs:282:28
    |
279 |         let concat = ParametricFunction2DConcat {
    |             ------ binding `concat` declared here
...
282 |         let concat_param = concat.get_parametric();
    |                            ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
283 |         let concat_param = Rc::new(concat_param);
284 |         let rep = ParametricFunction2DConcat::repeat(concat_param, 10);
    |                                                      ------------ cast requires that `concat` is borrowed for `'static`
...
290 |     }
    |     - `concat` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I know there is a lot of code here - happy to clarify anything - any ideas or thoughts would be very helpful! My main goal is to be able to do the combination of 1. and 2. - it may well be the case that there is some much better way of organising the whole thing that could help!

Comment: I think trait objects (`dyn Trait`) carry an implicit `'static` lifetime requirement (so it's like `dyn Trait + 'static`)

Comment: @Einliterflasche is probably right, and I also don't understand why you'd need Rc here. You might be able to use `impl ParametricFunction2D` instead and just clone the value over and over.
Another advice is that while polymorphism is possible in Rust, there might be more idiomatic patterns to do what you wish instead, that don't have a performance penalty. For example, you can go very far with generics for your particular use case and only keep `ParametricFunction2DConcat` with the trait object (to allow stuff with different types)